# Cooling power for cloud chamber

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics

I'd like to build a small Peltier cell cooled cloud chamber.

The cold surface would be a copper sheet with a surface of 200x200 millimeters.

Is there a way to even guess the cooling power needed to bring the copper sheet below -30°C ?

Comment: If you know someone who runs a LN2 cooled chamber of similar design their mass loss rate might provide a first estimate. Have Peltier coolers gotten a lot more efficient while I've been distracted?

Comment: I don't know if they got more efficient, probably that's not the case.

I saw a few designs that used peltier devices to achieve cool-enough temperatures to run a small (about 20-40 cm2) could chambers. I'd like to scale it up a bit, and I'd like to see if it's feasible.

There are peltier cells that can achieve around 70°C dTmax, and can suck 250W Qmax. You can trade heat pumping power for dT, so in the example above we can achieve 35°C dT and pull 125W.

This is why I need a reasonable upper limit for how much heat do I need to pump out of that copper plate.

Comment: ...or I could put some ice over it and see how long it takes to melt. Would give a ballpark number.